# Independent object positions in a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, directx-11

I'm using DirectX 11 and currently making it possible for the user to place objects where they are standing (cubes, for now).

I have a vector like this -

```
 std::vector<Cube> cubes;
```

and when the user presses a key, this code block executes to add a new cube to the vector (and set its position to the camera position) -

```
    cube = new Cube();
    cube->Init(md3dDevice, md3dImmediateContext);
    cube->SetOffset(eyePos.x, eyePos.y, eyePos.z);
    cubeOffset = XMMatrixTranslation(cube->GetOffset().x, cube->GetOffset().y, cube->GetOffset().z);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&cube->world, XMMatrixMultiply(boxScale, cubeOffset));
    cubes.push_back(*cube);
```

This does add a new cube to the vector but all previous cubes positions are overwritten to the current camera position (after moving), making it appear that only one cube is created and it is simply moved to camera position upon each button press.

here's a screenshot of my console window to demonstrate the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH4rZ.jpg

I also have an iterator calling all the cubes draw functions, after setting it's individual world matrtix.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Cube class is like this -

```
Cube.h

#include "d3dUtil.h"
#include "GameTimer.h"
#include <string>
#include "Point3f.h"
//-- simple vertex structure
struct Vertex
{
XMFLOAT3 Pos;
XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

 class Cube{

public:

Cube();
~Cube();

public:
void Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext);
void SetOffset(float x, float y, float z);
Point3f GetOffset();

void BuildGeometryBuffers();
void Draw();

XMFLOAT4X4 world;

private:

//-- Vertex and Index Buffers
ID3D11Buffer* mCubeVB;
ID3D11Buffer* mCubeIB;

ID3D11Device* md3dDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext* md3dDeviceContext;

Point3f mPosition;
  };
```

Cube.cpp

```
#include "Cube.h"

 //-- Constructor
 Cube::Cube(){


 }

 //-- Deconstructor
 Cube::~Cube(){
//-- safely release
ReleaseCOM(mCubeVB);
ReleaseCOM(mCubeIB);
 }

 void Cube::Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
 {
md3dDevice = device;
md3dDeviceContext = deviceContext;

//-- define vectors and indices 
BuildGeometryBuffers();

 }
 void Cube::SetOffset(float x, float y, float z)
 { 
 mPosition.x =  x;
 mPosition.y =  y;
 mPosition.z =  z;

 }
   Point3f Cube::GetOffset()
   {
 return mPosition;
  }
void Cube::BuildGeometryBuffers()
{
//-- Create vertex buffer
Vertex vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::White   },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Black   },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Red     },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Green   },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Blue    },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Yellow  },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Cyan    },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Magenta }
};

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;                      //-- Holds the vertex buffer resource description
vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;          //-- Only accessable by GPU
vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8;         //-- Size of buffer
vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;   //-- Bind the buffer as a vertex buffer to the input-assembler stage of the pipeline
vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;                     //-- No CPU access
vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;           //-- Holds subresource data
vinitData.pSysMem = vertices;               //-- Use the vertices as initialisation data
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mCubeVB)); //-- Create final buffer using all information


//-- Create the index buffer
UINT indices[] = {

    0, 1, 2,        //-- Front face
    0, 2, 3,

    4, 6, 5,        //-- Back face
    4, 7, 6,

    4, 5, 1,        //-- Left face
    4, 1, 0,

    3, 2, 6,        //-- right face
    3, 6, 7,

    1, 5, 6,        //-- top face
    1, 6, 2,

    4, 0, 3,        //-- bottom face
    4, 3, 7
};

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;                      //-- index buffer description, simple to vertex buffer
ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT) * 36;          //-- 36 indices
ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &mCubeIB)); //-- create final index buffer using all information
}

void Cube::Draw()
{
UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
UINT offset = 0;
//-- Set the created buffers
md3dDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mCubeVB, &stride, &offset);
md3dDeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(mCubeIB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

//-- Draw the cube
md3dDeviceContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You need to show use the definition of Cube

Comment: Added the Cube class now

Comment: Smells like a global variable for the cube location or an incorrect loop through the cubes array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be setting their individual world matrices, but you are never reading them. You have to get this matrix to the shader.

Comment: can't paste code here apparently, but I set them when calling the draw function like  world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&cube->world); This is done in a loop that iterates through all cubes. Then the matrix is set using SetMatrix before the draw